# Is there any reason to use <meta charset="utf-8">?

Tags: html

I understand that `<meta charset="utf-8">` declares the character encoding of the document to be UTF-8.

According to the [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#charset) `<meta charset="utf-8">` is not mandatory and the only allowed charset for HTML5 is UTF-8 anyways. So leaving it out does not hold back any useful information in an HTML5 document.

> Regardless of whether a character encoding declaration is present or not, the actual character encoding used to encode the document must be UTF-8.

However, almost every resource on HTML5 urges to use the tag despite it being redundant and  unnecessary with regards to the specs.

Is there any reason to use it?

Comment: @vee The Encoding standard requires the encoding to be UTF-8 but not its declaration. Therefore the requirements necessitate that the document's character encoding declaration specifies a string that matches "utf-8" "_if it exists_". You have left that part out. I edited my question to cite the relevant portion that makes clear that the declaration is not mandatory.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Google says its best practice.  I guess this caters for any new browser that does not default to utf8.  I think the effect is going to be minimal if you leave it out.  I have put it in to stop website checking sites from complaining about it.  And there is not much bulk to it.